# What does Figure 3 in the BERT paper represent?

Tags: deep-learning, transformer, bert

The [BERT paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1810.04805.pdf) has the following diagram (Figure 3):

[image]

It's captioned "Differences in pre-training model architectures".
However, I thought the BERT architecture was just a stack of attention blocks like this (from [huggingface](https://huggingface.co/blog/bert-101)):

[image]

My question: **What is the BERT diagram supposed to mean?**

My best guess is that it represents the process of predicting an output sequence from a given input sequence. In other words, in the GPT model, one first samples with a sequence length of 1 to get next token T1, then we embed T1 via E2 and sample with a sequence of length 2 to get T2, and so on.

In BERT, I assume we mask all input tokens but the first, then sample the whole thing.

The problem is that I don't understand what the `Trm` blocks mean, or how this relates to the BERT architecture.

Answer (score 1):

1. "BertBase" is basically what's inside the ellipses labelled "Trm" (attention heads + FF) - both for BERT and GPT.
2. The main difference is that BERT pays bidirectional attention while GPT is unidirectional (from left to right) or "causal".
3. T_N of GPT is the contextualized last token (embedding) which is used to calculate the next token.

Comment: So in general each `Trm` block outputs something of shape `(Batch, Seqlen, d)`, except in the output where each `T_i` selects the final sequence element?